# pandoc returning "Cannot decode byte '\xf9'"

Tags: r, pandoc

I'm downloading a webpage from within R using `xml2`, and then using pandoc to convert it to pdf.

My R code

```
library(xml2)
download_html("https://thehustle.co/apple-christmas-present", "test.html")
```

cmd line

```
pandoc test.html -o converted.pdf
```

This fails with the error

```
pandoc: Cannot decode byte '\xf9': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
```

I'm not sure whats going on here. If the webpage is not in utf-8 (and that is the root error), is there someway to convert it to?

Comment: Note that I've also tried to run this conversion using `wkhtmltopdf`, and this failed with `Exit with code 1 due to network error: ProtocolUnknownError`, so probably not just a pandoc error

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you could try:

1. Use pandoc directly: don't use a different tool, but let pandoc handle the download.

   ```
   pandoc https://thehustle.co/apple-christmas-present -f html -o converted.pdf
   ```
2. Use `iconv` to ensure that the input is really UTF-8 encoded:

   ```
   iconv -t utf-8 test.html | pandoc -f html -o converted.pdf
   ```

If neither works then it's likely to be a problem with the website.